# What is this plants with cup like flowers

Tags: identification, houseplants

What is this plants with cup like flowers? Are the cups flowers or something else?

[image]

[image]

EDIT:

It bloomed:

[image]

Comment: Where are you located? Is this your plant?  If so what was the colour of the flower?  Anything particular about them that stood-out?

Comment: The flowers are white. This is how I received the plant. @GardenGems

Comment: Thank you for telling me the colour.  Can you tell me what part of the world you are located?  Is this an indoor or outdoor plant?  Knowing your location makes it easier for others to narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: @GardenGems It is in New Delhi. I was told it's an indoor plant.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I feel like i know what it is, but I still can not think of a name.   One day it will come to me.  By then it will probably have bloomed for you.  Then you will know what it is or someone will.

Answer (score 2):

This is [Xanthostemon chrysanthus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xanthostemon_chrysanthus), commonly known as the **golden penda** or **first love**

> ...is a species of tree in the myrtle family Myrtaceae, endemic to (found only in) north eastern Queensland, Australia...

The cup like structures are flower-heads, having five petals in the side..

> Flowers bright yellow and bisexual with 5 petals attached to rim of calyx. Yellow stamens about 3 cm, surround centrally located style that is 3 - 4 cm long...

You can know more from [here](https://www.nparks.gov.sg/florafaunaweb/flora/3/2/3200).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a *Cestrum nocturnum'* or night blooming jasmine which has finished flowering. If the flowers are successfully pollinated, then berries will be produced, so it looks like yours weren't pollinated. It's a tropical climber and grows wild outdoors in places like the Caribbean, but can be kept as a houseplant, though it does need repotting periodically to allow it to grow on a bit. Information on this plant here https://homeguides.sfgate.com/nightblooming-jasmine-plant-care-38078.html

Comment: I checked images for the night blooming jasmine, and the plant looks different. Are you sure it is NBJ?

Comment: I have added blooming pics. Is it Golden Penda?